# How can I say for 64-bit, use the c:\program files (x86) and for 32-bit use the c:\program files?

Tags: windows, windows-installer, inno-setup, jnlp, java-web-start

I have to launch 32-bit icon module and in 64-bit also 32-bit icon module but the path is one issue while using JNLP/ws.

InnoSetup, how can i set if its 64-bit PC use `c:\program files (x86)\` not `(x64)` even. And for normal general 32-bit use `c:\program files\`

`ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64`

```
[Files]
; Install MyProg-x64.exe if running in 64-bit mode (x64; see above),
; MyProg.exe otherwise.
Source: "MyProg-x64.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; DestName: "MyProg.exe"; Check: Is64BitInstallMode
Source: "MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: not Is64BitInstallMode
Source: "MyProg.chm"; DestDir: "{app}"
Source: "Readme.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: isreadme


[Icons]
; Java Jar to Icon
Name: "{userdesktop}\Iconname"; Filename: javaw.exe; WorkingDir: {app}\dist; IconFilename: {win}\firefox2.ico; IconIndex: 0; Parameters: "-jar ""{app}\dist\Jar.jar"""
```

Comment: You shouldn't be hardcoding the path in the first place.  On localized or customized systems the correct path might not be either of these options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment out `ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64`.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use the constant {pf32}

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={pf32}\ProgramName
```